# Grabbing a specific element of an array in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I'm splitting a string by ';', but want to specifically grab the first and second element.

I know with PHP it's just simply $array[0], just can't find anything for this for Objective-C

```
NSArray *tempArray = [returnString componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
```

So here I have assigned my array, how can I go about getting the first and second element?

Answer (score 17):

Its just simply `[array objectAtIndex:0]` in Objective-C ;-)

Comment: ah ha! I was attempting to use: [tempArray indexOfObject: 0]; and getting nothing back! Cheers.

Comment: ;-) Its `objectAtIndex:` not `indexOfObject:`

Comment: With the new updates to Objective-C 2.0 `array[0]` is the same ad `[array objectAtIndex:0]`

Answer (score 5):

Starting with XCode 4.5 (and Clang 3.3), you may use [Objective-C Literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html):

```
NSString *tmpString1 = tempArray[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *tmpString = [tempArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"String at index 0 = %@", tmpString);
NSString *tmpString1 = [tempArray objectAtIndex:1];
NSLog(@"String at index 1 = %@", tmpString1);
```

You may also wish to do an IF statement to check tmpArray actually contains objects in before attempting to grab its value...

e.g.

if ([tempArray count] >= 2) {

// do the above...

}